# Set options in attribute of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

When I create a jQuery UI element (button for example), I do it like this:

```
<button class="Button" data-options='{ "text": false, "icons": { "primary": "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" } }'>Move Up</Button>
```

I have some JS which looks for anything that is `.Button` and extracts the `data-options` attribute as JSON and then creates the button passing in the options.

I'm wondering if jQuery UI has any built-in function to accomplish this instead? For instance, I'd like to be able to set options on the buttons within a Buttonset by putting the options in an attribute on each child button:

```
<div class="Buttonset">
    <input type="radio" id="SortDirection_Ascending" name="SortDirection" value="Ascending" />
    <label for="SortDirection_Ascending" title="Ascending" data-options='{ "text": false, "icons": { "primary": "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" } }'>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="radio" id="SortDirection_Descending" name="SortDirection" value="Descending" />
    <label for="SortDirection_Descending" title="Descending" data-options='{ "text": false, "icons": { "primary": "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" } }'>&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```

But jQuery doesn't know to apply the options. I could do this in JS like I am with buttons (and other widgets). But I'm curious if this is already supported with a different attribute.

**To clarify:**

When I create a widget, I want to know if jQuery can automatically extract the widget's options from an attribute on the element **and apply them to the widget**.

```
<button class="Button" data-options='{ "text": false, "icons": { "primary": "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" } }'>Move Up</Button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".Button").button();
    /* jQuery saw that this element has a "data-options" attribute and automatically
     * extracted the options from this attribute and applied them to the widget. */
</script>
```

Comment: Still your question is unclear. You will be able to access them as JSON, yes. :)

Comment: Your notes "I have some JS which looks for anything that is .Button" and "I can't really do that for a Buttonset" seem contradictory. Can you explain why you cannot do it for the div?

Comment: I want to know if there is a specific attribute name I can use which jQuery checks and applies the options contained within.

Comment: @TravisJ: you're right, after the `buttonset()` is created I can write some additional JS to go apply options to its children. I'll clarify that. I just want to know if jQuery has this functionality already built-in. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshM. - You mean like event delegation using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: @TravisJ: Added additional clarifications to post.

Comment: Why are you doing this with script at the client and not at the server? No javascript at all is required for that.

Comment: @RobG What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an attribute in the DOM element that you can set to accomplish this. You will have to either use the method you already are using, or set the options when calling the jquery ui .button() method on the button. For example:

```
$( 'button' ).button({
    icons: {
    primary: "ui-icon-locked"
  }
});
```

The only other way would be to manually include the classes and structure that jquery-ui does after you call .button(). For example:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-locked"></span>
  <span class="ui-button-text">Button with icon on the left</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question. That's all I needed to know (that it was not possible using built-in functionality).

Comment: Just to clarify, this functionality is not already built into jquery-ui, but it seems that you have already built the functionality that you need! :)

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to re-write things that already exist.

Comment: I will, I was waiting to see what anyone else had to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `data()` function is made for attaching data to DOM element:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

```
$(".Button").data('options')
```

This extracts data from a html element

http://jsfiddle.net/a5sVM/1/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I don't think.

Comment: " I want to know if jQuery can automatically extra the widget's options from an attribute on the element." That's exactly what data does, see my updated answer

Comment: Right...see my updated question for clarification. Also read dremme's answer - they got what I was asking. Thanks.